# Resource file works only in HomeController

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC application written in .NET 7
I started working on resource files to support another language as well. the problem I had, is that when I am changing language, it only works in HomeController, in OrderController it is not working at all. Before returning ViewResult in both controllers I am setting culture using code bellow

```
var ddlCulture = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ddlCulture");
if (ddlCulture is null)
    return;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlCulture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlCulture);
```

ddlCulture in this case is "pl";

Then in views I am using it like that

```
@using MyApp.App_GlobalResources

<h1>@Resource.ListOfOrders<h1>
```

[resourceCulture while in View in HomeController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpZwf.png)

[resourceCulture while in View in OrderController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFmmY.png)

Resource files are in `App_GlobalResources` folder.
Those files are named `Resource.resx` and `Resource.pl.resx`

Also, both HomeController and OrderController are in the same folder, in the same namespace.

Can someone explain, what I did wrong, that in HomeController it is working file, and in OrderControler it does not work?

I try:

1. putting resource files in App_GlobalResources
2. create those files from scratch using VS instead of Rider
3. creating new resource file specifically for OrderController (OrderController.pl.resx)

Here is Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)
https://github.com/pr0s3q/MinimalReproducibleExample.git

Login: admin

Password: admin

Extra info: while creating this MRE, it was working in Order\Index as well, until I change it to async function and return type to `Task<IActionResult>`

Comment: Please share a full [mre].

Comment: @GuruStron added. Please look at extra info at the end as well. It has something to do with this function being async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found fix for that. Instead of

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlCulture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlCulture);
```

I have now

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlCulture);
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlCulture);
```

In my case, this fix the problem